# Как сверстать элемент "Диапазон цен". Картинка пролагается

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать данный элемент(Диапазон цен). HTML + CSS + JS(если понадобится).

Comment: Используйте <input type="range">
Стилизацию можно прикрутить какую угодно

Comment: Приведите пример пожалуйста. Двигаться должно 2 ползунка. Range не подойдет.

Comment: zombie, да вы правы, не досмотрел(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот то что Вам нужно https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range
Это готовая библиотека, там есть и пример кода

Comment: Хотелось бы реализовать без использования jQuery

Comment: лучше всего основное указывать в теле ответа, в т.ч. пример кода, а ссылку выводить в качестве примера. Справка [**Почему и как удаляются некоторые ответы?**](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)